# Nodejs MySQL Random Table Insert

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to write a discord game bot like Town of Salem, Wolvesville, Feign etc.

I have a one table for users who used "join" command.
table name joinedplayer

```
gamerid discordid 
1       user1
2       user2
3       user3
4       user4
5       user5
```

And i have one table for gameroles
table name gameroles

```
roleid rolename
1      mafia1
2      mafia2
3      town1
4      town2
5      town3
```

I'm trying to when start command used create a playernew table like:
Table name playernew

```
playerid discordplayerid roleid
1        user1           5
2        user2           4
3        user3           1
4        user4           3
5        user5           2
```

When game stopped delete "playernew" and table and when game started create a new "playernew" table with different index

How can i do that?

Comment: It is difficult to understand for me!!

Answer (score 0):

In Sql, there is a concept called **Foreign Key**. So, you can relate tables with each other.

In your case, first create a **game** table, **id** must be your **primary key**

```
id      name
1   user1's game
```

then, add **gameId** to your **User** table

```
playerid discordplayerid roleid gameId
1        user1           5         1
2        user2           4         1
3        user3           1         1
4        user4           3         1
5        user5           2         1
```

To add **foreign key** to your **user** table

```sql
ALTER TABLE User
ADD FOREIGN KEY (gameId) REFERENCES game(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

So, If you just delete a game from **game** table, it will automatically delete all related users through **foreign key**.

Comment: If you are Turkish, you can write in Turkish.
I want to randomly relate the id. Also, the role id that has already been used should not be reused. I don't know what to do with the code.

Comment: You cant write in Turkish in this platform. In your code, you should fetch all role ids from the table and assign it to users in one transaction. as for random distribution, you should implement your own algorithm to perform it.